# MATLAB- How to find multiple x and y intersection points from two curves

Tags: matlab, intersection

on the plot below, the two curves intersect at 3 points. One on the left side, one in the middle, and one on the right side. I need to find the (x,y) coordinates for the three intersection points, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that. Below is my code so far and the plot:

[Click here for plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwXqx.jpg)

Here's my code:

```
% Define

b1=3.5;
b2=4.5;
rho1=2.7;
rho2=3.3;
h=40;
u2=(b2^2)*rho2;


f1=.15;
w1=2*pi*f1;
cvec=3.5:.01:4.5;
p2=1./cvec;
lhs=tan(h*w1.*sqrt((1./b1.^2)-(p2.^2)));
rhs=(u2.*sqrt((p2.^2)-(1./b2.^2)))./(u1.*sqrt((1./b1.^2)-(p2.^2)));

plot(cvec,rhs,cvec,lhs)
xlim([3.6 4.6])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails to execute (`u1` is missing). But anyway, you can subtract lhs-rhs and then look for the results [zero-crossing](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/267222-easy-way-of-finding-zero-crossing-of-a-function#answer_209072)

i.e.

```
zci = @(v) find( v(1:end-1).*circshift(v(2:end), [-1 0]) <= 0); % Returns Zero-Crossing Indices Of Argument Vector
zx = zci(lhs-rhs);
cross_points = cvec(zx)
```